# struts' ActionForm and using trim()

Tags: java, struts

if I need to trim what user sends in a form to trim it in ActionForm?

e.g:

I have MyActionForm class in which I have property

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {

   if(name!=null) {

       this.name = name.trim();

    }

}
```

Or is there any other good way?

thx.

Comment: Next time you don't know how to format something on SO (this time: code), use the buttons in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less cumbersome way is to use [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(name);
}
```

You can use either [`trimToEmpty`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#trimToEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) or [`trimToNull`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#trimToNull%28java.lang.String%29), whichever makes more sense for your application. It's even neater if you use a static import.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it in the [Action](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html).

You will know if the user left the field empty or if the user wrote some spaces in it.

So, your application could behave different in each case.

If you do the trim in the ActionForm you don't know what the user exactly did.